# How to write the SQL statements for a multivalued attribute?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, erd

How to write the the `SQL` statement for this diagram particularly for the
 multivalued attribute. How the sql statement will be?

Can anyone just help me out with this?

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear and you haven't specified a database.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Apart from anything else, CUS_NAME isn't a particularly good example of a multi-valued attributes.  Customers will tend to have one name; perhaps the name consists of more than one part, but in that case the parts are distinct attributes (e.g. FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of merge statement.

Comment: It's not fully answering question. Can you provide example usage of `merge`?

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.